# Use pre-fit lmfit model to predict values in new dataset

Tags: python, linear-regression, lmfit

I trained an lmfit model using the following:

```
xList = np.linspace(1, len(dataRowTrain), len(dataRowTrain))
model = LinearModel()
parameters = model.guess(dataRowTrain, x=xList)
fitModel = model.fit(dataRowTrain, parameters, x=xList)
```

Now I would like to use the fitModel to predict the next series of values in the dataset.  How can I do so?

I am aware I can output the weights of the best fit model and run it in the equation, but I am wondering if lmfit offers a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use to predict value

> model.eval()

Example:

```
result = model.fit(y, params, x=X) # curve fitting
x1 = [1, 2, 3] # input for prediction
a = result.eval(x=x1)   # prediction
```

Comment: This does not work.  result.eval(x=x1) fits a whole new model.

Comment: this is the method to predict new value. you can verify it by reading the [documentation](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#linear-and-polynomial-models)
use
plt.plot(x1, a)